# A command that ban multiple people at once

Tags: discord

I'm trying to make a command that ban mutliple people at once, using their ID. Here is my code :

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { MESSAGES } = require("../../util/constants");

module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {

    args.forEach(async id => {
        const users = await client.users.fetch(id);
        message.guild.member(users).ban;
        console.log(users);
    })
};
```

And here is my console output :

```
User {
  id: '409046637948829697',
  bot: false,
  username: 'NYRIANYRIANYRIA',
  discriminator: '4198',
  avatar: 'b7f3aed6450d28bbf5b4b1b24809edcb',
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 64 },
  lastMessageID: null,
  lastMessageChannelID: null
}
```

There's no error and nothing append when I run the command. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.ban is a function: GuildMember.[ban()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban)

```
args.forEach(async id => {
  const user = await client.users.fetch(id);
  const member = message.guild.member(user);
  if (member.bannable) member.ban();
  else message.channel.send("Cannot ban " + id);
})
```